# Python function arguments not deepcopies

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a two functions which are identical but set values for different values which look like

```
indices = [x for x in range(26)]
reflector = [0 for x in range(26)]
wiring = [0 for x in range(26)]

def generate_r(ind=indices,rf=reflector):
    while len(ind) > 0:
        smp = sample(ind, 2)
        for elt in smp:
            ind.remove(elt)
        rf[smp[0]] = smp[1]
        rf[smp[1]] = smp[0]

    return rf

def generate_w(ind=indices,wr=wiring):
    while len(ind) > 0:
        smp = sample(ind, 2)
        for elt in smp:
            ind.remove(elt)
        wr[smp[0]] = smp[1]
        wr[smp[1]] = smp[0]
        print(wr)
    return wr
```

I would have expected

```
generate_r()
generate_w()
```

To have returned to me two lists containing 26 distinct values between 0 and 25. However,what I find is that reflector is the list I want and w is still a list of all 0s.

Upon checking I found that indices was empty after running generate_r() which makes me think that python didn't pass a copy of indices to my function but a reference to the same object. Is this what is happening? If so, is there a way for the local namespace of the function to get its own copy without creating within the function itself?

Comment: you have to manually copy list: `ind = ind.copy()`. Or for older Python: `ind = ind[:]` Or using module `ind = copy.copy(ind)`. if there are nested lists then you need deep copy `ind = copy.deepcopy(ind)`

Comment: why does this happen for lists but not ints say?

Comment: because `int` uses less memory and it is easy and fast to copy single `int`. In many situation there is no need to create new list which need new memory and some time to duplicate it.

Comment: in C/C++ you can also send `int` "by reference" instead of "by value".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[furas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56895875/python-function-arguments-not-deepcopies/56895975#comment100337831_56895875) has already provided the solution to you. Below is why it happens.

```
>>> def increment(n):
...   n.append([4])
>>> L = [1, 2, 3]
>>> increment(L)
>>> print(L)
L = [1, 2, 3, 4]   # a changed!
```

The code `L = [1, 2, 3]` has the variable `L` refer to the list object containing references to three immutable objects: integer 1, 2, and 3.

[image]

As usual, when we pass `L` to `increment()`, the function has the local variable `n` refer to the same object as `L`:

[image]

The `.append()` method modifies the list in place, since list is mutable:

[image]

Since no new object is created and the change occurred in place of the object, when we print `L`, we get the modified list.

Answer (score 0):

One solution for you:

```
from random import sample

indices = list(range(26))
reflector = [0] * 26
wiring = reflector[:]

def generate_r(ind=indices[:], rf=reflector):
    while len(ind) > 0:
        smp = sample(ind, 2)
        for elt in smp:
            ind.remove(elt)
        rf[smp[0]] = smp[1]
        rf[smp[1]] = smp[0]

    return rf

def generate_w(ind=indices[:], wr=wiring):
    while len(ind) > 0:
        smp = sample(ind, 2)
        for elt in smp:
            ind.remove(elt)
        wr[smp[0]] = smp[1]
        wr[smp[1]] = smp[0]
    return wr

print(generate_r())
print(generate_w())
```